# ReactiveCrudRepository vs. R2dbcRepository

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, project-reactor, spring-data-r2dbc

I am learning the reactive stack starting with R2DBC and this is what I don't understand:

What are the differences between these, when to use them, and how relevant the `@Repository` stereotype annotation is to them?

- `org.springframework.data.r2dbc.repository.R2dbcRepository`
- `org.springframework.data.repository.reactive.ReactiveCrudRepository;`

As far as I understand, both of them are `@NoRepositoryBean` and both are shipped together through the `org.springframework.boot`:`spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc` dependency.

Comment: I don't know exactly but as I guess it seems that r2dbc is like jdbc for reactive and CrudRepository is part of the spring data framework for reactive. In other words, r2dbc is probably meant to be run on top of a specific reactive database driver and CrudRepository is a generalized interface for storage and retrieval of data. Providers in the data framework include solr, caches and the like. If you look you see r2dbcRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no difference between both, R2dbcRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository and not add any functionality ([R2dbcRepository java doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/r2dbc/docs/1.1.0.M4/api/org/springframework/data/r2dbc/repository/R2dbcRepository.html)), probably it's just a name convention, just like @Service has the same comportament as @Component.
About the @Repository annotation, you haven't to annotate any class that extends from repository interfaces to them work.